# Linq build a tree of posts

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

My example code only goes two levels deep and i would like it to keep traversing down the tree until it has no children. does anyone know how i can accomplish this using linq expressions

```
static List<Post> GetPosts(int postID) 
{
    var posts = from post in myEntities.Posts
           where post.PostID == postID || post.ParentPostID == postID
                select post).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not write recursive linq queries that can be translated into SQL with Linq2Entities. My suggestion is to bring the posts up into memory and traverse them or write a recursive SQL query using [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)